# Decent Mac HW confguration to create iOS Apps using XCode

Tags: xcode

I'm planning to buy Mac just to develop Apps for iPhone (iOS) using XCode. Hence, I need to know what a decent hardware configuration to develeop with XCode. 
Since I will only use it for iphone developemnt, i dont want to spend alot of money on it. But also I want to get a good hardware that will not give hard to time. hence, what apple hardware and configuration you recommend.

Thanks,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much any apple hardware will work fine. I have both a macbook pro (2010) and an iMac (2009) that work very nicely. However a big screen is a huge help especially when designing the gui parts of an application.

Comment: How about Mac Mini, is it OK?

Comment: Not really, especially the older ones do not have enough memory and upgrading the memory was a hassle. If you get a newer one, then buy one with more memory. But be aware that these boxes were not built for software development tasks (it looks like you are pretty tight on money, so it should be ok for you to make compromises).

Comment: The 2,3 GHz with 2GB is enough. You'll have to keep low the number of active applications or the system will freeze now and then to paginate. It's better if you get 4GB. You can buy third party memory from macsales.com if you are on a budget.

Comment: a mini will be fine but do get 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Thanks .. you mentioned that a big screen is important. I'm thinking to buy Macbook pro which have 13 inch sceen. would 13 inch will be fine, or should I go to 15 inch.

Answer (score 2):

I use a 2011 model MacBook Air with 4GB of RAM and runs XCode like a dream.